# Changing ct100 clientID prefix when using Master Pages

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, .net-3.5, master-pages

I'm searching for a way in C# to change the ct100 prefix client id when using Master Pages in .Net 3.5. I've done this successfully in VB using the following snippet on the Master Page code behind...

```
Private Sub InitSub(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Init
  ID = "master"
End Sub
```

I am aware of `clientIDMode="Static"` which will not work in .Net 3.5.

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3441141/what-is-ct100-and-how-do-i-rename-it) was helpful, but I can't seem to translate it effectively into C#. Please help!

Comment: Are you doing this so you can get the ID in javascript?

Comment: Yes. I use javascript for form validation. I simply prefer shortest naming convention possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For what it's worth:

```
protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

      ID = "master";

}
```

With [`AutoEventWireup=true`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.pagessection.autoeventwireup%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)(default) you can use the page-methods when you follow the naming convention: `Page_EventName`.